# JMeter - Using a variable for a HTTP (SOAP) Request Body with variables inside the body variable - implanted variables not being resolved in request

Tags: variables, soap, jmeter, request

In order to create a JMeter HTTP Request that can send varying types of SOAP envelopes I created a file based variable that contains the SOAP envelope which is then referenced in the Body element to provide the required SOAP Request Body. **${SOAP_Envelope_Body}** Note: This is my only Sampler type to be used - for both simplicity and compatibility reasons.

By also using custom Properties in a .properties file for things like SOAP Action for the Authorisation Manager element etc everything works perfectly, I can easily test any Webservices based on the hard coded SOAP envelope bodies supplied by the body envelope data file.

My problem is that I now need to be able to add variables inside the hard coded SOAP body variable to allow it to take in additional data from another variable data file so that I can then re-use the same Webservice body, but with different data each iteration.

In LoadRunner I could have parameters (variable in JMeter) nested inside a parameter and they would resolve, in JMeter this does not seem to work, so how can I achieve the following then:

An example **${SOAP_Envelope_Body}** variable SOAP body from my input file could contain the following elements with the **implanted variables** that need to be evaluated at runtime in my request, but are not currently being resolved in the actual HTTP Request that is sent by JMeter.

**Example SOAP Body Element Variable with Implanted Variables:**
<WM_REL>**${Var1}**</WM_REL>**${Var2}**<ADDR_LN_1>StreetName</ADDR_LN_1>

**Expected Request Body with Implanted Variables Evaluated and Sent:**
<WM_REL>**Patient**</WM_REL>**12345**<ADDR_LN_1>StreetName</ADDR_LN_1>

**Actual Body Request Sent:**
<WM_REL>**${Var1}**</WM_REL>**${Var2}**<ADDR_LN_1>StreetName</ADDR_LN_1>

How can I resolve the variables at runtime, I have looked at a custom pre processors but without much coding knowledge or examples to go from, without success. Any advice, with examples if possible would be greatly appreciated. JMeter must be able to handle variables inside variables if it's overpriced counterpart, LoadRunner can!!

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it into [__eval() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__eval) like:

```
${__eval(${SOAP_Envelope_Body})}
```

this way all nested [JMeter Functions or Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) which are inside the `${SOAP_Envelope_Body}` variable will get resolved to their respective values.

More information: [Here’s What to Do to Combine Multiple JMeter Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables)

Comment: Thank you for the above  - so simple compared to what I was expecting, and like I train my engineers, keep it simple wherever possible so others can follow what is done, and this seems to match perfectly with what I was after. Most appreciated Dmitri!

Comment: A perfect response to what was needed Dmitri!